# LaTeX it! won't compile simple code

Tags: compiling, incompatibility, tools, software

I just dowloaded the add-on LaTeX it! for Thunderbird. I'm a one-hour beginner. Something must be very wrong with me or with LaTeX it!.

Indeed, I wanted to compile, inside Thunderbird, a text containing a lot of simple stuff between dollar symbols (the text contained no TeX mistake, since I could compile it in TeXMaker without any trouble).
Compiling the whole text did not work, but if I cut the text in three-lined pieces, adding them piece by piece, and compiling in the meantime, and it worked.

I also noticed that sometimes, compiling twice induces mistakes, or sometimes works again. It looks like closing the new message window resets something, somehow, but I don't understand what.

It is hard to provide you with examples of failing code, because when I cut the failing code into pieces to identify the mistakes, it suddenly works. Or sometimes, everything is erased after I press the LaTeX it! button.

Am I missing a general thing ? Are there specific ways to use LaTeX it! ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm writing an email containing "blablabla $formula$ blablabla $other formula$ blablabla" and that's basically all.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was misguided, I was thinking about something else called by (almost) the same name.

Comment: (As I said, that comment was deleted for a reason.) I see there are links to a support site and a support email on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/latex-it/, so if you don't get any tips here, that's another way to go. Exactly how does fail though, what does "not work" mean?

Comment: It either produces a wrong formula, or erases part (or everything) of the text, or leaves the TeX as it is (I mean, between dollars). That is, it fails in almost all possible ways ! I'll look at your link, though. Thanks !

Comment: Imho (but I don't have latexIT) latexIT sets everything by default inside an align*-environment. So additional $..$ will confuse it heavily.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Plop is referring to a Thunderbird addon, so it's likely https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/latex-it/ and not https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/.